# When is the product of two injective functions, also injective?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm currently, by curiosity, investigating when the product of two injective functions, is also injective. My condition is that this is true if and only if there $\nexists x_1, x_2 \in X$ such that $f(x_1) = g(x_2)$ and $g(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Here's my reasoning, I hope someone can confirm / disconfirm it, or leave some response.

**Proof.** Let's suppose we got two functions: $f: X \mapsto Y $, and $g: X \mapsto Y $, where the function $h(x)$ is defined as the product between the two:

$$h(x) = f(x)g(x)$$

The definition of an injective function, states that for some $x_1,x_2 \in X$ where $x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$. Which then also holds for $g(x)$.

Let's use this fact for our newly defined function:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
h(x_1) = f(x_1)g(x_1)\\ 
h(x_2) = f(x_2)g(x_2)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

If $h(x)$ is injective, then: $x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow h(x_1) \neq h(x_2)$. Because $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are injective functions, the statement is true only and only if $f(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$ and $g(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$. $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \square$

Can this be interpreted graphically, where the functions can't have any common y - values if I haven't misunderstood myself? Is there any other way to interpret the given result?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tanamas Ah, that's right: there's $e^{\alpha x}e^{\beta x}=e^{(\alpha+\beta)x}$.

Comment: Your question is phrased in terms of an arbitrary set $Y$, but you assume that there is an operation of multiplication on the set $Y$. Please state the question more precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement that $h$ is injective if and only if $\nexists x_1, x_1$ such that $f(x_1) = g(x_2)$ and $g(x_1) = f(x_2)$ is incorrect. Consider $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x + 2$.

Then $h(x) = x^2 + 2x$. Note that $h(0) = h(-2)$. So $h$ is not injective.

Now suppose we have $x_1, x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = g(x_2)$ and $f(x_2) = g(x_1)$. Then $x_1 = x_2 + 2$ and $x_2 = x_1 + 2$. Then $x_2 = x_2 + 4$. Contradiction.

Comment: Should that be $x_2 = x_1 + 2$ instead of $x_2 = x_1 + x_2$?

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it isn't injective. Counterexample:

Let be $f: \{0, 1\} \to \{-1, 1\}$ such that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = -1$

$f^2(x)$ is the constant $1$, which is not injective for multiple possible inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying functions is actually typically how functions fail to be injective.

Consider a simple example: $x \mapsto x$ is injective, but $x \mapsto x \cdot x = x^2$ is not. In fact, the latter is 2-to-1 at every point except $x = 0$.

More generally, if a function "looks like" $x \mapsto (x - c) \cdot (x - c) \cdots (x-c) = (x - c)^n$ near a point $c$, then in a sense that can be made precise, the function is locally $n$-to-1.